# what does "volatile pair" mean in love/romance relationship?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Recently, I am studying Chinese Zodiac Compatibility. They said "**Snake (one born in Snake year) and Rat (one born in Rat year) are a volatile pair**".

I am not sure what "volatile pair" mean? like each person can go to different direction in their life or something like that? or they just do not like to each other

See the website here http://www.travelchinaguide.com/intro/social_customs/zodiac/compatibility.htm

Comment: Did you look up what "volatile" means?

Comment: I did it got many means and I do not know which one

Comment: Basically, they are saying that the innate natures of opposing signs will always be in conflict.  For example: I am a Tiger, my husband is a Monkey. (This is considered to be the worst possible combination.) I am pathologically critical, my husband is chronically offended. Everything is okay, as long as he doesn't see me rolling my eyes.

Comment: @Oldbag - Incorrect.  It means that the relationship is unpredictable and explosive.

Comment: @HotLicks - "Unpredictable," yes. "Explosive"?  Seriously, Hot Licks, do you honestly think it is being stated that a relationship could cause the spontaneous combustion of the parties involved? I believe the term "volatile" was being used in a figurative, rather than scientific, sense. IMO, the word "conflict" suffices.

Comment: @Oldbag - What I'm arguing with is "always".  A volatile relationship is not *always* in conflict -- it's variability is what distinguishes it as "volatile".

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/volatile.

> You fight and make up frequently if the two of you have a volatile
>   relationship.

An example would be the relationship of Richard Burton and Elizabeth Taylor, who were married and divorced twice, and was by all accounts **tempestuous**: "You can't keep clapping a couple of sticks [of dynamite] together without expecting them to blow up" - Richard Burton.

Answer (score 0):

The site provides no context at all for the phrase other than general romantic relationships, so there can be no definite answer. But one presumes it's used as in [sense 3](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volatile)—given to extremes of emotion. That could be good or bad, and may vary widely. The prototypical example of such a relationship would be Shakespeare's *Romeo and Juliet*. One minute they are declaiming undying love for each other; the next, they are committing suicide.

Comment: But they were committing suicide **because** of their love. A volatile pair would be more likely to "run hot and cold"... meaning one minute they love each other desperately and the next they can't stand the sight of the other.

Comment: That's a good example of what I had in mind. In a volatile pair, love might at times be expressed as hatred or loathing. Can you think of an example?

Comment: @Jason, why not sense 1 or sense 5? why sense 3?

Comment: If we're looking to Shakespeare, maybe _Taming of the Shrew_ would be a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Leo married to an Aquarius... Tnis relationship is very volatile. At times i feel i will die without my Aquarius and the Aquarius needs to know that no matter what he does i will continued to be his biggest cheerleading fan. I only know we need one another's Love.. Cause we both are learning others valuable emotions. However its brings on pain to us both cause we hate that we love one another and make our friends feel lefted out of what we think is love. We both have a Job to do and mainly is letting each other go without looking back.. This relationship is a struggle and only the strong serve.

Comment: This isn't the type of answer that English Language & Usage generally seeks—it's anecdotal, somewhat scattered, and lacking in documentation from third-party sources—and yet it somehow manages to capture the idea of what "volatile pair" means in a love/romance relationship remarkably well, I think.